# How to do a Rapid Descent in a jet with inoperative spoilers?

Tags: safety, aircraft-design, emergency, cabin-pressure

So, let us assume you are in a simulator for your favorite jet plane, and the instructor gives you a LOFT (Line-Oriented Flight Training) scenario that goes as follows:

1. A normal takeoff and climb to cruise altitude, and perhaps thirty minutes of normal cruise flight
2. The non-recoverable loss of speedbrake (flight spoiler) functionality due to a mechanical jam, or some other malfunction such as the loss of all SECs in a FBW Airbus.
3. Another 30 minutes of time to deal with the first malfunction: run the checklists, plan and initiate a diversion if needed.
4. You lose normal cabin pressure for some reason, and have to conduct a rapid descent to get back to 10,000' and complete your diversion.

How do you execute the descent, considering that the rapid descent procedures for most jets rely on using the speedbrakes to achieve a high descent rate without overspeeding the aircraft?  To use the 737 QRH checklist for Emergency Descent as an example:

> EMERGENCY DESCENT . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .Announce
>
> The captain will advise the cabin crew, on the PA system,
>   of impending rapid descent. The first officer will advise
>   ATC and obtain the area altimeter setting.
>
> ENGINE START switches . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . CONT
>
> THRUST levers . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . CLOSE
>
> Reduce thrust to minimum or as needed for anti-ice.
>
> SPEED BRAKE . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . FLIGHT DETENT
>
> DESCENT . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .Initiate
>
> Target speed . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Mmo/Vmo
>
> If structural integrity is in doubt, limit speed as much as
>   possible and avoid high maneuvering loads.
>
> Level-off altitude . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Lowest safe altitude
>                                             or 10,000 feet, whichever is higher

Comment: Whenever I see a question title like this, I imagine some pilot somewhere hurriedly typing out his question hoping for an answer before he hits the ground...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple.

FOLLOW THE MANUFACTURES PROCEDURES.

In some aircraft (I don't have a 737 flight manual handy) there is an altitude limitation if the spoilers are inop for just this scenario.  When the aircraft was certified, they needed to demonstrate an emergency descent (in the allowable time) without them, and that might not be possible from the certified ceiling. If that's the case in the 737, then descend to the max altitude with spoilers inop (assuming that you started above it).

If there is no altitude limitation and no special spoiler-inoperative emergency descent procedure (I have never seen one of those, but there's nothing to say that a manufacturer couldn't have one) then you simply fly the regular procedure without spoilers.  The manufacturer had to demonstrate this during certification and it must have been acceptable at the time.

As rbp says, most of the time you fly Mmo/Vmo at idle power after you don the oxygen mask.  IF the flight manual/checklist says that you can put the gear down (some do) then you may, but I wouldn't otherwise.  I certainly wouldn't **slow** to gear speed (unless the manufacturer says to....  Unlikely in a jet like this) because you are decreasing the drag by slowing, and taking time at altitude to do so.

Comment: good answer. cruise in the flight-levels in my aircraft (M20M) is near or below Vlo (140), so I can put the gear down immediately. Vle is 165, so that's the airspeed of an emergency descent, with gear down and the speedbrakes out (which have no operating limitations). gets about 4000fpm descent, which is 4 minutes from the service ceiling of 25,000ft down to 10,000.

Comment: @rbp Is that what the manufacturer procedure says to do for your airplane?

Comment: yes, and that's what I practiced at the Flight Safety Mooney course in San Antonio. I got a high-altitude endorsement in a 737 level D at Continental

Answer (score 7):

Go to the top right corner of the envelope and stay there (point D in the sample below. Sorry, I don't have the 737 envelope at hand). Engines idle, speed and load factor as high as allowed.
[image: flight envelope]

If airframe integrity is not critical, lower the gear to increase drag, but expect to lose the gear doors.

Comment: Can you post a larger version of that figure, or point me at where I can find one?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: I took it from the [Wikipedia page for "flight envelope"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_envelope). Try [this](http://code7700.com/g450_flight_envelope.html) - I will replace the picture in my answer with it.

Comment: So, starting from cruise flight, you'd pull the engines back to idle, then pitch up past alpha-crit to initiate the descent? In other words, you'd be stalling at high IAS to emulate the airflow separation and resulting sink you'd otherwise get from the deployed spoilers?

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: Not at all! Yes, power to idle, but then nose down and a steep turn, so the load factor goes up. Nose down as much as needed to stay at maximum speed.

Comment: So, basically, a split-S-like then!  Thanks!

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject: Not like a split-S at all! Spiralling descent with down pitch at most 15-20° while keeping tightest turn allowed (60-70° bank, 2-2.5G load for typical airliner).

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject More like a steep spiral. A split-S is a roll to inverted and half loop to end up right side up with a 180 deg course reversal. You wont find that in any transport category abnormal procedures.

Comment: Ah, thanks for straightening me out then, pardon the pun.  I'm not sure why my brain didn't get to a spiral descent straight away from your description!

Comment: This is the correct answer for a non-transsonic aircraft. In  transsonic aircraft, like a 737, the max allowable airspeed is not constrained by Vne, but by Vmo

Comment: And unlike Va, Vne is not calculated based on structural considerations but aerodynamic ones.

Comment: I would strongly recommend following the manufacturers recommended procedure (which was probably determined using this or a similar method, along with other considerations) rather than creating your own....

Answer (score 3):

Whenever trying to rapidly descend, you always want to think drag!

Throttle to idle, lots of s-turns, (aileron drag), get down to gear speed, drop the gear, and lower flaps if practical.

A limited crabbing-like manuever (intentional side-slipping) would greatly slow the aircraft as well!

I'm sure that Terry will be here to recant us with a tale soon!

Comment: Although I am hesitant to say flaps, because they increase lift.

Comment: +1 for mentioning [sideslipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slip_(aerodynamics)) and Terry. I am waiting myself ...

Comment: NEVER SKID AN AIRPLANE, it will cause it to flip over.

what you want to do is a sideslip, not a skid

Comment: @rbp It won't flip, (unless you done goof), but you are correct, a sideslip is more accurate.

Comment: "unless you done goof"? what does that mean? Next time you're in the air, initiate a 30 degree turn, keep feeding in the rudder on the downward wing side of the aircraft. Make sure you've got a parachute on, and are in an aircraft certified for aerobatics and are at an appropriate altitude. I'll post my unusual attitude training video later today.

Comment: here's me in a skidding demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juu7JoSDE1A

Answer (score 2):

There primary consideration in an emergency descent is to descend at the maximum allowable airspeed in the given configuration.

In a jet, this is based on the "barber pole" on the airspeed indicator (which changes based on altitude).

If the speedbrakes fail, you won't get the maximum descent rate, but you won't break the airplane by flying outside the aerodynamic envelope, either.

Here's a jet-type airspeed indicator with a red and white barber pole: http://www.md80.it/cockpit/cockpit/captain/kuvat/asi.jpg

(I have a high-altitude endorsements as per 61.31(g))